# registered trademark Ⓡ symbol superscript issue in Nexus devices

Tags: android, symbols, superscript

I am working on an application which has lots of Ⓡ in its navigation drawer and action bar. The superscript tag is working fine for all the Nexus devices (tested on galaxy s3, s4 and s5). I have tried doing below sample:

```
This is a dummy <sup><small>&reg;</small></sup>
```

But when I tested it on Nexus S and Nexus 5 the Ⓡ symbol is not appearing properly. After searching on Google I found that there is some problem with the Nexus devices reading superscript tag.

I am stuck with this issue.

Comment: Your entity reference is missing the `&` character.

Comment: acutually i forgot to add '&' while posting the question. Please look at the editted question.

Comment: How are you trying to use this snippet of HTML? In a `WebView`?

Comment: no using a text view. and the limitation is that i can't use webview here..

Comment: I am not aware that `Html.fromHtml()` handles entity references. How are you trying to convert this HTML into something that a `TextView` can show?

Comment: \u00AE instead of the entity reference?

Answer (score 0):

Try the SuperscriptSpan like following, replace the startIndex and endIndex with the position of your trademark character. Be careful with the size of the text, you may need some density independent size here probably to make it work on all screens.

```
    Spannable span = new SpannableString(title);
    span.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(null, 0, 60, null, null), (int)startIndex, (int)endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    span.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), (int)startIndex, (int)endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(span);
```